# javascript get second variable from array

Tags: javascript, variables

I have javascript that is checking multiple fields in Dynamics CRM. If some of them or all are "1" it will use the highest value to use in a calculation.
I pasted a part of the script:

```
var level1 = {
percentage: 0, 
label: "MyLabel"
}

var level2 = {
percentage: 0, 
label: "MySecondLabel"
}

if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("conditioninterested").getValue() == 1) {
    level1[0] = 50;
}

if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("revenueconditionquote").getValue() == 1) {
level2[0] = 70;
}

var chance = Math.max(level1[0],level2[0]);
```

How do I get the corresponding label after the Math.max found out the percentage to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way your data is structured I would add the level objects to an array and then filter by `chance`. `filter` returns an array so you need to take the first element `[0]` which is an object, and then the label value from that object.

```
var label = [level1, level2].filter(function (el) {
  return el[0] === chance;
})[0].label; // MySecondLabel
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/xj074dub/)

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are could have made a constructor function to declare the object instances, secondly **level1** and **level2** are objects, So basically there are two ways you can access object properties:

- Dot notation, eg. level1.lebel or level1.percentage
- the [] notation. You need to put the key in, not the index number. Objects don't have indexes, they are key and value pairs. and also they are un-ordered.